# Makefile: Select to compile against dynamic or static library programatically

Tags: c, linker, makefile, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I develop a software that needs to be compiled against libraries coming for an external supplier. In some cases the libraries are available as shared libraries (libexample1.so) or as static libraries (libexample1.a).

I want my makefiles to be able to detect that situation. My idea is to check for the static library file, and if it does not exist redefine some compile flags.

My code now is this:

```
$(PROGRAM1):$(PROGRAM1_OBJS)
ifneq ("$(wildcard $(STATIC_LIB_PATH)","")
    @echo "Compiling against static library"
else
    @echo "Compiling against dynamic library"
    STATIC_LIB_PATH = ""# SETTING IT TO EMPTY
    LDFLAGS += -lexample1 
endif
(compilation instructions)
```

This is not working for me as it is trying to execute the STATIC_LIB_PATH... Any suggestions on how to approach this situation? Is this the best approach or are there better ways to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set make variables, you must do so outside of a recipe. Inside of a recipe, it will be interpreted as a command to execute.

In your case, you can move the assignment before any rule

```
ifeq ("$(wildcard $(STATIC_LIB_PATH)","")
    STATIC_LIB_PATH =  # SETTING IT TO EMPTY
    LDFLAGS += -lexample1 
endif

# ...

$(PROGRAM1):$(PROGRAM1_OBJS)
    (compilation instructions)
```

Usually, you don't need to check for static vs dynamic libraries. The compiler and linker already select the proper library. So, you only need to specify

```
LDFLAGS += -lexample1
```

and the linker picks the dynamic version if available, and the static one if there's only a static library.